# Agora cloud recording

Tags: google-cloud-storage, agora-cloud-recording

I want to integrate Agora cloud recording with Google Cloud Storage. I hit the rest API with Postman. When I start to recording, I get this response:

```
{
    "resourceId": "OCfVcGcrjEnDtjdTKErMJzWJJJWH-WS62dnUjlZSusn38EF09ln_XHH89CGxpqHX1SS5QmSrf42pegEz6THZYfCct_XkqVhY3wXTPNJxXS8no6uD5LG1tSHKDZ8IC_UxX_76MuA8rIC_mg1IH6fv8cd5EKxXPpl5bD9UMqZQLZP4Q2wuRmwWZy4Xhg7KFpWKxA1y-wBryxD1h3RjMVu6Q6mBd6eHmei794DTojBg4yk",
    "sid": "",
    "code": 432,
    "reason": "webResource is not allowed for this scene!"
}
```

I dont know what thing was false, please help me, thanks

I can record and video file on Google Cloud Storage